# Eclipse GC overload when integrating AdMob?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, admob

My application was working perfectly until I tried to integrate Google's AdMob for Advertisements. When I try to load my game it takes about 5 minutes until it crashes and tells me the GC has overloaded forcing me to close out of the workbench. I have added the Google Play Services adk to my project and can use the libraries with no problem. I have added the activity into the AndroidManifest.xml and have created a basic AdView in my code. I am using Java rather than xml for my view.

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   </application>
```

Java:

```
    private AdView adView;
private LinearLayout adContainer;


public Game(Context context) {
    super(context);
    highscore = new Highscore(context);

    adContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    adView = new AdView(context);

    setupAdview();

    private void setupAdview() {
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5164799584891368/6168391539");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    adContainer.addView(adView, params);
}
```

Could someone please tell me how this is supposed to be done or what Im doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

These are a few logcat messages, none of them really seem too dangerous

```
Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
GC_CONCURRENT freed 952K, 7% free 14845K/15943K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 16ms
```

Theres just a bunch of these messages..

Comment: Please include the error message in the question, as well as anything that looks suspicious in logcat.

Comment: The odd thing is there are no error messages. Eclipse just tries to open the application for 5 minutes or so and then it crashes due to a 'GC overhead limit exceeded'(Thats literally all the message says.) It then tells me I need to close eclipse, and I can't even get to the logcat. There are a few lines related to GC that I havent seen before, so il post them here

Comment: Okay, so this is a workstation-side failure, not a device-side failure, and it's the Eclipse GC that's flailing. (I edited the question's title to reflect this.) Have you tried increasing the memory limit for Eclipse?

Comment: I have not tried that no. If that were to be the fix, how would this effect the application when its not being run through eclipse? Is it not something wrong with the application? How did this happen? All I did was add the google play services sdk and code to make an ad

Comment: If Eclipse is blowing up, fix Eclipse, and worry about the app when you have that problem. If you want to see what the app looks like without Eclipse, disconnect the USB cable and launch it. I don't know why this is happening... but the first thing to do when Eclipse starts thrashing memory is to give it some more and see if that helps.